# How to get top most parent Id when I click on any one of its child element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
    <div class='firstDiv'>
         <div class='firstDivChild1'></div>
         <div class='firstDivChild2'>
              <div class='firstDivChild2_Child1'></div>
              <div class='firstDivChild2_Child2'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='secondDiv'>
         <div class='secondDivChild1'>
              <div class='secondDivChild1_child'>
                   <div class='secondDivChild1_child_child'></div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my requirement is when I click on any div I want to get an top most parent Id (i.e. `parentDiv`). Presently I'm using the below script to get parent Id:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('div').click(function(e){
   var parentDivId = (e.target).parentNode.id;
   alert(parentDivId );
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone correct this code to reach my requirement?

Comment: can u define clearly level of topmost?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I need the id of first div, i.e. <div id='parentDiv'> id

Comment: <html> elements don't have id's :P

Comment: It is still unclear what you want.  If someone clicks on `firstDivChild2_Child1`, what id do you want?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want id which is having name 'parentDiv'. when I click on document other than these divs, I don't want any Id.

Comment: my guess is the OP wants to grab the top most parent 'div' from any 'div' clicked.  recursion would solve the problem.

Comment: @rkw something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226488/601179) ?

Comment: Why do you care so much, @gdoron? @Pravallika69 will [most probably](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1302468/pravallika69?tab=questions) **not** [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) your answer anyways..?

Comment: @Pravallika69 - you've asked 9 questions and NEVER accept an answer.  That is not how SO works.  Go back to your previous questions and pick the best answer and accept that by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Otherwise, some people will find little point in trying to help you because you aren't rewarding anyone for helping you.  You should also upvote all answers that provided some help.

Comment: @fragmentedreality sorry to say this, some times the solutions are doesn't satisfies my requirement. And also I don't know that I should upvote an answer which provide some help. That's why I didn't do anything, nothing more. Don't mind plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('div').last().attr('id'));
    return false;
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3Njd/)

Comment: Who knows what they want?  I suspect the OP doesn't speak english very well because even direct questions are getting unclear answers.

Answer (score 2):

If that parent DIV is unique across document, then you just can refer to it by ID, i.e. $('#parentDiv'), but if it's not, then you should change your HTML and add to **parentDiv** some class (i.e. parentDiv), and you'll be able to refer to it by this expression $(this).parents('.parentDiv:first');

Answer (score 1):

then use [the natural power of event bubbling](http://jsfiddle.net/kkDeS/). any descendant clicked will bubble up the event upwards (hence bubble) and will act as if the parent is clicked. so adding a click handler to the parent also does the same thing.

```
$('#parentDiv').on('click',function(){
    var id = this.id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this little function :

```
$.fn.root = function() {
  var $all = $( this[0] ).parents(); 

  // omit "html", "body" and one index to the last item;
  return $all.slice( $all.length - 3, $all.length - 2 );
};
```

Sample Usage :

```
$('input').click(function() {
    alert($(this).root().prop('id'));
});​
```

[Simple working example using your HTML here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ5jA/)

Answer (score 0):

It is still not completely obvious what you're asking for, but based on a few of your comments, here's my best guess.

Using event bubbling, you can examine all clicks in your document and you then determine where the click originated with `e.target` and you can then figure out whether that click originated in your div tree or elsewhere:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    // determine if click was in our div tree or not
    if ($(event.target).closest("#parentDiv").length) {
        // click was in our parentDiv tree
    } else {
        // click was not in our parentDiv tree
    }
});
```

Regardless of where the click was located, you can get the top of your div tree `id="parentDiv"` at any time with this with this jQuery:

```
$("#parentDiv")
```

If, you just want the top-most div that is above what is clicked, no matter where the click is in the document, you can use event bubbling like this to get that:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var topMostDiv = $(e.target).parents("div").last();
    // do whatever you want with topMostDiv here
});
```